# Determine matrix P so that $A = P \centerdot D \centerdot P^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I need to determine the matrix P so that $A=P \centerdot D \centerdot P^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. The matrix $A$ is given by

```
A = 
  {{31, -10, -4, -4, 10}, {-6, -19, 5, 25, 7}, {80, -5, -13, -35, 19}, 
   {-2, -20, 4, 24, 8}, {-40, -5, 9, 25, -3}}
```

Comment: See first application in this documentation page https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvectors.html

Comment: Not sure what the update is about. If can be diagonalized, then it can be diagonalized by the eigensystem (and, of course, conversely). The `B` matrix in the update is not diagonal.

Comment: @yode. I do not find your update an improvement to the question because your matrix `A` does not meet the OP's requirement of being a diagonal matrix. I suggest you remove it,

Comment: @m_goldberg Ok,I have.

Comment: If one knows the math, this is a trivial thing to do in *Mathematica* (see Coolwater's comment). If not, then it's primarily a mathematics question. If it's a question about a computational issue related to the standard diagonalization, then clarify.

Answer (score 7):

First you should check

```
DiagonalizableMatrixQ@a
True
```

Then

```
{s, j} = JordanDecomposition[a];
a == s.j.Inverse[s]
True
```

That's all!

Answer (score 4):

Writing:

```
a = {{31, -10, -4, -4, 10}, {-6, -19, 5, 25, 7}, {80, -5, -13, -35, 19}, 
     {-2, -20, 4, 24, 8}, {-40, -5, 9, 25, -3}};

p = Transpose[Eigenvectors[a]];

d = Eigenvalues[a] IdentityMatrix[Length[a]];

invp = Inverse[p];

a == p.d.invp
```

I get:

```
True
```

which is what you want.